# How to send list of byte arrays to json

Tags: android, parameter-passing, json

How i can pass  `ArrayList<byte[]>` to `JSONObject` as a parameter?

For example, I need to send a Id (string), Name (string) and photoList `(ArrayList<byte[]>)` in a json object.

Comment: Do you want to convert your `ArrayList` to json?

Comment: What's in the list? Just the name of the photo or the bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GSON LIBRARY . The code you need can be as :

```
String jso;
jso = new Gson().toJson(photoList);
```

It should convert the arraylist(i.e. `photoList`) to jsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [GSON](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html)lib for this if you want to convert arraylist into json

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library use the following code to convert your `ArrayList` to JSON.

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(yourArrayList);
```